# Frame overlapping

Tags: filters, audio, computer-vision, continuous-signals

I 'm reading the following article from NVIDIA which involves some audio processing a the beginning : [link just here](https://users.aalto.fi/~laines9/publications/karras2017siggraph_paper.pdf) (part 3.2)

I don't understand the following part :

> In practice, we use 520ms worth of audio as input, i.e., 260ms of
>   past and future samples with respect to the desired output pose. We
>   chose this value to capture relevant effects like phoneme coarticulation
>   without providing too much data that might lead to overfitting.
>   **The input audio window is divided into 64 audio frames with 2x
>   overlap, so that each frame corresponds to 16ms (256 samples) and
>   consecutive frames are located 8ms (128 samples) apart.** For each
>   audio frame, we remove the DC component and apply the standard
>   Hann window to reduce temporal aliasing effects. Finally, we calculate
>   K = 32 autocorrelation coefficients to yield a total of 64×32
>   scalars for the input audio window. Although much fewer autocorrelations,
>   e.g. K = 12, would suffice to identify individual phonemes,
>   we choose to retain more information about the original signal to
>   allow the subsequent layers to also detect variations in pitch.

What does a 2x overlap mean ? And also what are these samples they are talking about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two times overlap just means that data from each frame appears in two other frames.

[image: Frame overlap diagram]